# Conditional routing in routerLink if URL exist Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am generation a side navigation, some of the objects have URL property and some don't (they are used for generating submenu).

my HTML template looks like this

```
<li *ngFor="let menu of navMenu;index as i" routerLink="{{menu.url}}">
....some stuff
</li>
```

I need that if the `menu.url` exist then do the routing , else do nothing , right now if menu.url don't exist it goes to `/ route.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a check using *ngIf

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let menu of navMenu;index as i">
  <li *ngIf="menu.url"  routerLink="{{menu.url}}">
    ....some stuff
  </li>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: But I want to render the li

Comment: Yea that can be done ... but is there someway I can set value of menu.url to something that it does not do the routing

Comment: you can use conditional routing as

Comment: <button [routerLink]="menu.url? {{menu.url}} : []"></button>

Comment: It worked , one update 
<button [routerLink]="menu.url? [menu.url] : []"></button>

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `menu.url` has an absolute path, just do something like:

```
<li *ngFor="let menu of navMenu;index as i" [routerLink]="menu.url ? [menu.url]: []">
....some stuff
</li>
```

Comment: Tried the conditional routing also but , the [] matches to "/" route. I need it to ignore the routing

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore the routing"? When menu.url is null, no link should be generated? (basically clicking on the li element would have no effect)

Comment: You are right , I was having some other issue thats why it was getting routed to the / , after correcting , it says at the same route thanks